# Restricting unused generic causes compile error

Tags: rust

I don't understand why restricting an unused generic causes a compilation error. Why does this compile:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct B;

fn is_eq<T>(b: B, c: B) -> bool 
// where
//     B: PartialEq<T>,
{
    b == c
}
```

but uncommenting the where clause causes this compilation error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:9:10
  |
4 | fn is_eq<T>(b: B, c: B) -> bool
  |          - this type parameter
...
8 |     b == c
  |          ^ expected type parameter `T`, found `B`
  |
  = note: expected type parameter `T`
                     found struct `B`
```

Making the `==` explicit compiles i.e. `PartialEq::<B>::eq(&b, &c)` - although shouldn't it be clear to the compiler to use this implementation? Strangely, changing the input parameters to &B and using `==` compiles. Would be great to know why there is an error and what is going on here.

Comment: Reminds me of [this scenario](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3e21292d3ddc667e937a75e54fa0b68) where a generic `T` can use `.into()` to create another `T` because of the identity implementation via `From`, but introducing a `T: Into<...>` makes it no longer work. Don't recall where that discussion was originally from, probably some chalk thread.

Comment: [This Rust user forums thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/trait-bounds-and-method-lookup/67345) also seems relevant, seems like the bound forces `PartialEq::<T>::eq` to the top of the candidates and the compiler is unable to recover once it sees the other type is incompatible somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has existed since Rust 1.0:

- [Reordering where clauses can change program behavior](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41756)
- [Trait impls from where clauses (ParamEnv) take precedence over freestanding trait impls](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24066)

Another way to get both `B == T` and `B == B` is to specify both:

```rust
fn is_eq<T>(b: B, c: B) -> bool 
where
    B: PartialEq<T> + PartialEq<B>,
// also works: B: PartialEq<T> + PartialEq,
```

When you use `&B`, it mostly ignores your where clause since you're no longer comparing `B` values. Instead, it goes through [the blanket impl for references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26B%3E-for-%26A), which is apparently enough to find `PartialEq<B>`.

You can make the reference one not compile by changing the where-clause.

```rust
fn is_eq<T>(b: B, c: B) -> bool
where
    for<'a> &'a B: PartialEq<&'a T>,
{
    (&b) == (&c)
}
```

Comment: This exact error is more likely to be due to this bug - https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24066. The rest of an answer isn't changed by this fact though.